# Browserify: How do I apply "--exclude, -u" using package.json?

Tags: javascript, browserify, package.json

I need to use `--exclude, -u` within package.json rather then as a command line option, but how?

From: `browserify test.js -u request > test.browserify.js`
To: `browserify test.js > test.browserify.js`

Potential solutions:

1. --exclude has a package.json option similiar to --ignore: `"browser": { "request": false }`
2. --exclude can be enabled, or its functionality copied, using "transform" somehow `"browserify": {"transform": ...}`
3. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Add the following to package.json: `"browser": { "request": "./request.js" }`

Create `./request.js` and put the following in it:

```
var req = "request";
module.exports = require(req);
```

And you have to put the "request" string in a separate variable, if you don't the `require` will just return an empty object stub `{}`.

The downside of this is that I have to define such a file for every module I want to require, ideally I'd have a single file that can detect what to require.

**Edit**

Haven't tested this yet but I could probably dynamically require these modules without an external file `var req = "request"; var request = require(req);`